# MVC 5 SQL calendar plotting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, calendar

I've been Googling back and forth for a MVC 5 calendar-solution which is able to plot dates into a calendar, I've found a few different kinds but they all seem to be for older versions of MVC, and some of them are quite expensive compared to my budget, so my question is if any of you know a way to do this? Or do you know of any already existing open-source or at least free calendar solution for MVC?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [Full Calendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) - javascript, and you can provide REST services to feed event data into it. And its free.

Comment: Per the close reasons, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow."

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - I see where you are going, however, I am not simply asking you to "recommend" or find something for me, I am asking you to tell me which tool works well with MVC, and which one is open-source etc., as I haven't been able to find them myself on Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if you find something for MVC 3 or 4, for sure it will work correctly in MVC 5, because from MVC 3 everything what was added is more like extension. There isn't any breaking changes.

Second thing: I'm almost sure that you need something in client side without re-rendering views. There are some posibilliteis which you can use and integrate with your system like: fullcalendar.io or jquery-week-calendar

Comment: I think I'm going to go with FullCalendar, thank you very much!

Comment: You probably see this before, but if not: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/638674/Full-calendar-A-complete-web-diary-system-for-jQue

Comment: Yeah, I found that one after searching Google for "fullcalendar MVC", thanks!